# How to read application yaml properties from custom maven plugin?

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin

How do i read properties from application.yaml in custom maven plugin?

The file name varies, it can be application.yaml/yml/properties.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that already does that:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
    <artifactId>yaml-properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>src/main/resources/application.yml</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

From that point, you can use any of the `application.yml` properties in the pom itself, like this:

`${spring.datasource.url}` or `${spring.datasource.password}`